# How to use a double formatter in SAPUI5?

Tags: xml, sapui5, formatter

I am trying to use a double formatter for a StandardListItem, based on certain conditions (which will be evaluated in javascript), I want a CSS class to be applied.

my code is as below.

```
<StandardListItem 

class = "{= '{path: \'' + ${path: 'lineItem>', formatter: 'path.to.formatter'} + '\', formatter: \'.anotherFormatter\'}' }"

 icon = "{= '{path: \'' + ${path: 'lineItem>', formatter: 'path.to.formatter'} + '\', formatter: \'.anotherFormatter\'}' }"> 

</StandardListItem>
```

In the above case, the formatters for icon are being called, but for class, the formatters are not being called, is it something which is not supported or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The attribute "class" is currently not bindable, but you can use method [addStyleClass](http://veui5infra.dhcp.wdf.sap.corp:8080/sapui5-sdk-internal/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Control.html#addStyleClass) to add your specific CSS class. If you don't want to do that you could also [write custom data to the DOM](http://veui5infra.dhcp.wdf.sap.corp:8080/sapui5-sdk-internal/#docs/guide/1ef9fefa2a574735957dcf52502ab8d0.html) and use this data as described in the example.